# how to update rows in data frame in pyspark , the table is in serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am trying to update few rows in dataframe using pyspark , the table exist in Serverless SQL pool

I did try yo use Update command but the error is it is not supported in serverless SQL pool, is there any way possible update few row in Azure synapse Serverless SQL Table

Comment: Can you add some more details or an example to what you are trying to do, and the expected result as at the moment it is not clear how we can help you if you can't show what you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating tables which are created using ADLS data source in serverless pool as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002)
**Serverless SQL pools don't support updating Delta Lake files. You can use serverless SQL pool to query the latest version of Delta Lake. Use Apache Spark pools in Synapse Analytics to update Delta Lake.**

Read the data from path  with below code:

```
df = spark.read.load('abfss://<containerName>@<ADLSName>.dfs.core.windows.net/mycsv2.csv', format='csv',header=True)
```

[image]

Update the data according to the requirements using below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
df = df.withColumn('<colName>', when(<condition>, '<updateValue>').otherwise(df.<colName>))
```

Create a linked service of ADLS. And write the data frame into ADLS with below code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    pdf = df.toPandas()   
    pdf.to_csv('abfss://<filepath>/mycsv2.csv', storage_options = {'linked_service' : '<linkedserviceName>'})
    print("done")
```

**complete code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
import pandas as pd

df = spark.read.load('abfss://rakeshsynapse@rakeshgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/mycsv2.csv', format='csv',header=True)
df = df.withColumn('Name', when(col('Id') == 1, 'AE').otherwise(df.Name))
pdf = df.toPandas()
pdf.to_csv('abfss://rakeshsynapse/mycsv2.csv', storage_options = {'linked_service' : 'AzureDataLakeStorage1'})
print("done")
```

[image]

The data will be update successfully.